# PHP reading database with a variable

Tags: php

I want to read 5 attributes of the database. The 5 attributes have the names `post_image_1`, `post_image_2`, `post_image_3`, `post_image_4` and `post_image_5`. Now I want to show the 5 images on my page, with a for loop.

Here is the loop:

```
for($i = 1; $i <= 5; $i++){
    echo "<img src='image/$row[post_image_$i].png' height='250px' width='250px'>";
}
```

Now I get an error:

```
Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '$i' (T_VARIABLE), expecting ']' in
```

I hope that's enough info to help me. :P

Comment: You are trying to mix a constant and variable name together in your array index key as far as PHP is concerned.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since you're using arrays, do this:

```
for($i = 1; $i <= 5; $i++){
    echo '<img src="image/'.$row['post_image_'.$i].'png" height="250px" width="250px">';
}
```

Comment: beat me by seconds... :)

Comment: `A` for effort ;)  - in fact, if OP catches this, you can take the answer points - the upvotes already got me back over 2,000 -

Answer (score 2):

Try this, using string concatenation, it gets at the right field in the array. I'm assuming $row is declared already and contains the keys 'post_image_1', 'post_image_2'...

```
for($i = 1; $i <= 5; $i++){
    echo "<img src='image/" . $row['post_image_' . $i] . ".png' height='250px' width='250px'>";
}
```